# PHP array data convert to JS ( Canvas JS )

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I am trying to make a graph of my own data (JS)which I have stored in a php array

Now I have to make some kind of loop to make(Javascript)

```
  dataPoints: [

              { x: 10, y: 10 },
              { x: 20, y: 15 },
              { x: 30, y: 25 },
              { x: 40, y: 30 },
              { x: 50, y: 28 }
              ]
```

Needs to be something like

```
 {x: $arraytime[0], y:arraycloud[0]) , 
 {x: $arraytime[1], y:arraycloud[1]) , 
 {x: $arraytime[2], y:arraycloud[2]) ,
```

etcetera.

I have no clue how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a json_encode for this, if you prepare the array in php, like this:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraytime); $i++) {
    $arr[] = array('x' => $arraytime[$i], 'y' => $arraytime[$i]);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: This worked. Now I ahve another problem X: 140222 is time and should be displayed as 14:02:22 .. how can i do that?

Comment: You're going to want to look at PHP's date function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Uhm ye sure .. but i need to figure out how to display 140222 as 14:02:22 instead of 140,222

Comment: You'll want to use PHP's date function for that.

Comment: I'm happy to elaborate if you'd like, but can you mark this answer as accepted so the thread isn't left open?

Comment: Click the check mark under the score for my answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png